# Opel corsa 1.4t 2016 mixing coolant into oil

Tags: oil, coolant, leak, gasket, astra

My opel corsa 1.4t with B14net engine is mixing coolant into oil as result oil tank fills above max. I have cylinder head checked and is fine,replaced gasket and oil cooler and temperature is fine. It emmits a lot of white/grey smoke.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the cylinder head and cylinders crack checked?  If they weren't and were found fine, I'd suggest there might be a crack. Was the head checked for flatness? Was there an overheating problem before which precipitated checking the head and changing the head gasket? The "white/grey smoke" you are seeing is almost certainly antifreeze going into the combustion chamber.